# Barn doors that angle into the entry way

Tags: doors

I have just installed barn doors into a livingroom entry. (approx 6ft opening) It is 2 doors on a single track with offset. The issue I'm having is the doors are angling INTO the entryway. There is sufficient wall clearance at the top of the doors but the bottom of the doors are rubbing at the bottom of the wall. Any ideas how to fix this problem?

Comment: Barn doors usually have a guide attached to the floor to keep the bottom from swinging into or away from the wall.

Comment: Indeed a floor quide very similar to what you would find at the bottom of sliding glass shower doors.

Comment: Do the installation instructions give you any indication of what to do to prevent this? Was there some sort of stop piece that should be installed on the floor to hold them vertical?

Comment: I have 11 barn doors on my place mine are heavy duty with wheels on both side of the tracks and the doors hang straight the wheel at the bottom of mine is to prevent the door from being pushed out. I have seen single track doors and on those the hardware is usually offset to take up the “lean” or what ever is causing them not to hang “square”. I would make sure your hardware is properly attached a photo of the attachment of the hardware may help us spot the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You need a [Floor guide.](https://duckduckgo.com/?t=ffsb&q=barn%20door%20floor%20guide&iax=images&ia=images) Most are installed on the floor, sometimes  they attach to the wall at the base of the door.

They come in a variety of kinds, some just plane plastic, some with rollers, some adjustable ETC.

You can buy them or  you could make something from materials you already have on hand.   It really is just a tab or roller that keeps the bottom of the door from swinging into or away from the wall.

You should check with the manufacturer of your doors track/hardware to see if they have one that matches the spacing of the tracks you have. If not it will not be difficult to place one at the appropriate distance from the wall to match that spacing.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Without a bottom track, I can think of three issues:

The wall is not vertical (plumb) but the doors are.

The doors are not plumb, which means they are not attached correctly to hang straight underneath the track support (such as you mounted the door on the wrong side of the hanger.)

There's an air current pushing the doors into the wall (such as a duct blowing into the space and a return on the other side of the doors.)